# Can you solve this numerical puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking

Puzzle goes like:

3, 2, 12

10, 4, 9

8, 6, 3

9, 6, 2

7, 4, (?)

Can you answer what can be the (?) mark, with explanation

Comment: Is this a puzzle of your own devising or does it come from somewhere else?

Comment: It's by my own devising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is

> 12

Reasoning:

> Think about an analog clock:
> 3 - 2 -> 1 hour, 2 - 12 -> 2 hours
> 10 - 4 -> 6 hours, 4 - 9 ->  7 hours (continuing counterclockwise)
> 8 - 6 -> 2 hours, 6 - 3 -> 3 hours
> 9 - 6 -> 3 hours, 6 - 2 -> 4 hours
> In each one the # of hours goes up by one, so:
> 7 - 4 -> 3 hours, 4 - 12 -> 4 hours

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer! Congrats!

Comment: In other words, [(ROT13) Gur guveq ahzore ba rnpu yvar rdhnyf gjb gvzrf gur frpbaq ahzore, zvahf gur svefg ahzore, zvahf bar, zbq gjryir, jvgu erfhygf enatvat sebz bar gb gjryir (v.r., mreb vf cebzbgrq gb gjryir).](http://www.decode.org/?q=Gur+guveq+ahzore+ba+rnpu+yvar+rdhnyf+gjb+gvzrf+gur+frpbaq+ahzore%2C+zvahf+gur+svefg+ahzore%2C+zvahf+bar%2C+zbq+gjryir%2C+jvgu+erfhygf+enatvat+sebz+bar+gb+gjryir+%28v.r.%2C+mreb+vf+cebzbgrq+gb+gjryir%29.); i.e., [(hover over this)](/. "C = 2B - A - 1 (mod 12)").